# Delimiting a string

Tags: c++, string, delimiter

In a text file, I have several lines and each line looks like the below one (different numbers).

```
[275, 61],[279, 56],[285, 54],[292, 55],[298, 57],[315, 57],[321, 54],[328, 54],[335, 56]
```

When it comes to one line, I want to get each point separately.

For example:

- first I should get `[275, 61]`
- then I should get `[279, 56]`
- and then `[285, 54]`

However when I tried the following;

```
istringstream linestream(line); 

while (getline (linestream, item, ','))
{
               ...............
}
```

what it gives me is :

```
           first [275 
           and then 61]
           next [279
```

etc.

Can anyone tell me how to modify the `while` loop so that I get the required output ?

Comment: Isn't the behaviour you are getting the correct one, since the delimiter is `,`?

Comment: use std::string::find("],["); instead

Comment: To fix it, get the whole line into a string, and manually parse it. And no, you can't just look for `','`, you have to look for a `']'` followed by `','`, and to be on the safe side you should probably make sure that it's further followed by `'['`. And you should probably be able to handle white-space between the characters as well.

Comment: @40two :actually, what I want is [275, 61] and then [279, 56] etc.

Comment: @Nishi I think that 40two means that the behavior is correct the way you *use* the `std::getline` function. It's not correct for you, since you're using `std::getline` wrong (for your purposes).

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you see is the expected one since your delimiter is ','. If you want to delimit on every second ',' you need to concatenate your tokens back two by two.

For example "[275" + "," + " 61]"

Given your current output you should be able to do so with a simple for loop over your tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are experiencing using `getline` is the correct one, since you are delimiting with `,`.

In order to get the desired behaviour and if your compiler supports C++11 you could use the regular expressions library (i.e., `regex`) like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
  std::string str("[275, 61],[279, 56],[285, 54],[292, 55],[298, 57],[315, 57],[321, 54],[328, 54],[335, 56]");
  std::regex e("\\[\\s*\\d+\\s*\\,\\s*\\d+\\s*\\]");
  std::smatch sm;
  std::regex_search(str, sm, e);
  std::cout << "the matches were: ";
  while (std::regex_search(str, sm, e)) {
    for(auto x : sm) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    str = sm.suffix().str();
  }
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d732b9073662547f)

Comment: As I've commented on another answer on this question, *please say why your solution works, and say how it works*.

Comment: @zyboxinternational My solution uses [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/). To explain how regular expressions matches patterns, I think it's out of the scope.

Comment: Still, your solution is unlikely to help other programmers since it isn't explained. A brief explanation (one-two sentences) explaining why `regex` works in this case would likely improve the answer.

Comment: if there is no way of using C++11 and you think the regex solution works (regex is one of my favorite tools when it comes to text processing) have a look at http://www.pcre.org/

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that the text is coherent (no missed '[' or ']') You can manually search for position of '[' and  position of ']', and then you can copy the sub-string between those for further analysis. 
The following code demonstrate how you extract and print those sub-strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    const char* test=" [275, 61],[279, 56],[285, 54],[292, 55],[298, 57],[315, 57],[321, 54],[328, 54],[335, 56] ";
    char pair[20];
    int i,pos1,pos2;

    for (i=0,pos1=0,pos2=0; test[i]>0; i++)
    {
        if(test[i]=='[') pos1=i; //searching for '['
        if(test[i]==']') pos2=i; //searching for ']'
        //if(test[i]==']') printf("%.*s\n", pos2-pos1+1, test + pos1); //direct print from memory
        if(test[i]==']') strncpy_s(pair,sizeof(pair), test + pos1, pos2-pos1+1); // copy result sub-string to "pair"
        if(test[i]==']') printf("%s\n", pair); //print result on screen
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on why your solution works; answers comprising entirely of code with no explanation are considered 'low-quality' on Stack Overflow. Your solution uses up slightly more memory than the original (bugged) one; please keep to the original code, and don't completely re-code if it's not needed (which it certainly isn't for this question).

Comment: -1 for `<conio.h>` - for those who don't know, this is a severely deprecated header, not available on all systems, and it varies widely between systems that do have it. Using it is a **terrible** programming practice.

Comment: @anthropomorphic Explain please.

Comment: @anthropomorphic Thanks. What you say is true, since it impedes the program's ability to be multi-platform.